# How to correctly parallelize an inner loop within a parallel region?

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp, pragma, parallel.for

I am trying to parallelize inner for loops inside a parallel region:

```
    int num_threads, num_procs,max_row;
    double start_time;
    int i,h;
    # pragma omp parallel default(none) \
      shared(A,x,b,n,num_threads,num_procs,start_time,max_row)
    {
        int id = omp_get_thread_num();
        if (id == 0)
        {
            num_threads = omp_get_num_threads();
            num_procs = omp_get_num_procs();
            printf("Number of processors: %d\n", num_procs);
            printf("Actual number of threads: %d\n", num_threads);
            start_time = omp_get_wtime();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)   // for col 0 ... n-2
        {
            // partial pivoting    
            max_row = find_max(A,n,i);
            if (i != max_row)
            {
                swap_rows(A,n,b,i,max_row);
            }

            # pragma omp for 
            for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)  // for each elt under pivot
            {
                double scalar = A[j*n+i] / A[i*n+i];
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) // update values across row
                {
                    A[j*n+k] -= (scalar * A[i*n+k]);
                }
                b[j] -= (scalar * b[i]);
            }
            // implicit barrier
        }

        for (int h = n-1; h >= 0; h--)
        {
            x[h] = b[h] / A[h*n+h];
            #pragma omp for 
            for (int l = h-1; l >= 0; l--)
            {
                b[l] -= A[l*n+h] * x[h];
            }
        // implicit barrier
        }
    } // end parallel region
```

I don't understand how I can control the threads so that only one thread computes the outer for loop header and not all threads. Wouldn't it be inefficient to have all threads do the outer for loop header? My book recommends it is better to have one parallel region rather than two #pragma omp parallel for statements but it is confusing when you have so much code inside the parallel region.

Comment: If you restrict the parallel region to the omp for, default settings of omp_wait_policy should still keep the thread pool active.  An inner loop omp simd may be needed for optimization.

Comment: Or read up on single and master constructs (but beware, one has an implicit barrier and one doesn't...) https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpse24.html#x118-4380002.16 https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu38.html#x60-1090002.8.2